# Robustness of the Brown–Forsythe test against a change of skewness or other moments

Tags: lognormal-distribution, robust, variance-test

Consider the case of two random variables obeying [log-normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). Suppose that the $\mu$ parameters are equal but the $\sigma$ parameters aren't. This would imply that not only the variances-, but the skewness and kurthosis, etc., would also differ. Would this cause a problem if we were to apply the [Brown–Forsythe test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%E2%80%93Forsythe_test) for the equality of variances? Would the p-value of the test be reliable?